# php, include/require and different file encodings

Tags: php, encoding, include, require

When include'ing or require'ing files in PHP that have different charsets, I have a problem with mixed encodings:

file1.php (encoded in NON utf-8)

```
 <?php
    define('SOME_STRING', 'something encoded in non-utf-8');
 ?>
```

file2.php (encoded as utf-8)

```
<?php
    include('file1.php');

    echo 'something in utf-8';
    echo SOME_STRING;
?>
```

I can solve this as long as file1.php is under my control.

But e.g. if file1.php is from an external lib which gets automatically synchronized and I cannot convert (since it's overwritten), how can I change this?

Comment: I’d first of all think very carefully, whether I wanted to use such a library in the first place. (Who manages to not use UTF-8 these days, might mess up lots of other things, too …?) // If the `echo SOME_STRING;` parts is your only problem here - then go look into PHP’s mbstring and iconv functions.

Comment: No, it's not just one string etc. I mean if an external lib is full of non-utf-8 strings.

Comment: Than that’s a shitty lib that should not be used in the first place …? I mean, you could perhaps replace your own include with some code that reads the file content, converts the encoding, and then evals it or something ... but that won’t help you with includes/requires the lib does internally, plus it creates a maintenance and probably also security nightmare.